# Solve the following equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{107}$ :

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Solve the following equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{107}$:
$$ 101 · x − 6 = 4. $$
Hint: You may use the Euclidean algorithm to compute $ 1 $ in $\mathbb{Z}_{107}$.

It's right for  $x=34 $ I calculated it but not in a good way. I just calculate it for $x=1,2,3,4,... $

I think we need to calculate the inverse of $ 101 $ in $\mathbb{Z}_{107}$ and it's $ 18. $ 
But then, I don't know what to do.

Comment: If you know inverse of $101$ is $18$ you can just add $6$ to both sides and multiply both sides by $18$. (You can do this because $18$ is invertible).

Comment: @Carla_display You can always multiply both sides of an equation by anything in the proper domain. I take it your point is that since $18$ is invertible, we know this won't introduce any extra solutions.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, my point is that doing that results in an expression equivalent to the original, and not just one that is implied by the original one.

Comment: Actually, $89$ is the inverse of $101$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{107}.$ Or as in the answer below $89\equiv -18$ modulo $107.$

Comment: Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse is $-18$.
Then $101x=10$ and so, multiplying by $-18$ gives $x$ as $-180$ modulo $107$ and this is the same as $34$.